# Reference books in security and privacy preservation

Tags: protocol-design, implementation, reference-request

I am looking for books or reference guides to learn and teach "cryptography, security and privacy preservation techniques"? I need some advice to good resources that I can use.

Comment: You can ask this in the chat.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking for resources and not about a specific topic on cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

You can start your learning
https://www.coursera.org/learn/crypto/home/welcome
An excellent course to start with all about Symmetric/Asymmetric encryption/TLS/MAC etc.
A free ebook is also available https://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/cryptobook/BonehShoup_0_4.pdf

https://www.schneier.com/books/applied_cryptography/